# How to programatically get WhatsApp messages from local database on a rooted device?

Tags: android, mobile, root, whatsapp

I have a rooted device and I would like my app to read WhatsApp IMs from local database. I know there are a couple of similar questions out there but I couldn't find a working example.

When I manually go to internal storage/WhatsApp/Databases I can see there are a couple of encrypted databases in there:

```
msgstore.db.crypt12
```

Can anyone please provide me with a working example?

Note: I don't want to use AccessibilityService/ NotificationsListenerService to read the messages and my device is rooted.

Comment: You will have to do some reverse engineering to figure out how the database is encrypted and provisioned. WhatApp provides no public API for third parties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I found that this solution is working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22612144/2610933http://)